# Stack Gaming at PAX (the Penny Arcade Expo)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, conferences

[PAX East](http://east.paxsite.com/index.php) is coming up soon (April 6th-8th, Boston, MA), and while getting passes is difficult for the average plebian, there's still a little section...

> #### Exhibitors
>
> Interested in exhibiting at PAX East 2012? Contact Bill Butler (paxsales@paxsite.com) for info on booth space and sponsorships.

Really late to be bringing this up, but there's always the next PAX in probably ~6 months' time.  The [last time I mentioned it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2059/2259), it was well-received but I don't think anything came out of it.

Comment: I hope we get some people going and doing some coverage. We had people at Comic-Con I believe, but I never saw much in the way of blog posts or meta posts after the fact. :( I wanted to hear about how awesome it was!

Comment: I was really hoping there'd be something for PAX East since I'm only 1 hour from Boston.

Comment: I'll be personally visiting PAX East on my own dime, but as far as official SE presence, I'm not entirely sure *what* we'd do a panel or booth on or such.

Comment: @GraceNote sounds like a Seth Rogers question, hit him up if you see him.

Comment: @NickT There may be some creative ways (beyond hanging out and meeting people) we can engage at a big conference like PAX, maybe in the future we can figure out a good way of trying this type of outreach.

Comment: @SethRogers were you thinking more of a panel (see [previous post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2059/2259)) or just being on the floor (as FAE suggested on said post)

Comment: @NickT interesting post, thanks. There are creative ways of being on the floor and perhaps a panel presence may be successful too. Just recently started to think about this. If you have any new thoughts around it post about it and we can start a dialogue about some potential options for the future!

Comment: @SethRogers are you the sole point of contact for community regarding the business side of things now?  I was unclear if Brett was ever doing anything like that