# Which employees handle us?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Beyond the every-day community reps (e.g. GraceNote), who at StackExchange manages the site (from a non-technical point-of-view)?  Is it fairly nebulous where everyone works on every site, or do some of the employees have particular sites they work on, and which are relevant to us?

I've seen the following people around, what are their roles at present (beyond being the "next-level" CHAOS community reps)?

- Seth Rogers (CHAOS guy, seemingly announces most of the stuff nowadays)
- Lauren (CHAOS member that used to work on English.SE, posted some of the LoL contest stuff)
- Brett White (was a CHAOS guy here, but now seldom seen)

Comment: You're missing Jin (MASTERWORK LASER SCULPTOR)

Comment: Also David. And occasionally Balpha pops his head in for technical things that have to do with promos and/or chat.

Comment: @Raven - Jin works on everything, like the devs.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Jin and Balpha I'm lumping in with the boring technical staff.

Comment: What do you mean by Lauren being a former CHAOS member? Did I miss some memo?

Comment: @NickT JIN GAVE US LAZERS. LAZERS ARE CATEGORICALLY NOT BORING.

Comment: @IvoFlipse nope I'm still around! Maybe Nick meant I was formerly working on English.

Comment: @IvoFlipse ^ that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most people at SE Inc do a lot more than their job titles. So the short answer is, everyone works on everything, or is aware of what's going on with all of our sites.

Just about all of the new UI features are actually done by the core dev team, I help out sometimes with the UX and visual polish. They also monitor site stats and watch for irregular patterns.

Lauren is the CHAOS member who's officially assigned to the Gaming.se for promotional stuff. She and Seth came up with the ME3 promotion and other sponsorships. She's working on some other exciting promo ideas right now. Seth and Brett are focusing on other SE sites right now.

David, our CTO, is an avid gamer. He's been heavily involved with gaming promotions too. He and Sean came up with SkyrimvsMW3 and Hat Dash. He's also been working on the future [branding](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/a-new-name-for-gaming-stack-exchange) for gaming.se.

GraceNote represents our community team when it comes to gaming.se. As you know, he was hired from this community.

Ben and Emmett have been working on gaming.se promo dev work. e.g. mini contest sites, gaming.se site takeover etc. That's why you see their names here or in chat sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jin!

Comment: We miss you, Brett!